# What is "AARE" in AppArmor profiles?

Tags: apparmor

The man page for [apparmor.d (5)](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/manpage_apparmor.d.5) uses the syntax element `AARE` in several places, such as in `SIGNAL PEER = 'peer' '=' AARE`.

The definition for `AARE` is this:

```
AARE = ?*[]{}^
See below for meanings.
```

My question now is: where is this "below"? I suspect `AARE` to maybe mean "AppArmor Regular Expression" but I simply cannot find anywhere in the AA documentation any explanation for it. Googling or DuckduckGo'ing for "apparmor AARE" simpy draws blanks except for the man page where I cannot find any explanation "below". There is a section about "Globbing" but it is totally unclear to me if the `AARE`s (regular expressions?) are actually refering to "globbing" -- but then globbing isn't regular expressions.

So what are `AARE` and what is their syntax examples, as I really don't understand the meaning of `?*[]{}^`.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [discussion of my original question on the AppArmor mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/apparmor@lists.ubuntu.com/msg10441.html) the simplified answer is: yes, AARE means "AppArmor Regular Expression". However, AAREs are nearer (shell) glob expressions, but with additional AppArmor variable expansion using the `@{VAR}` syntax. This is not to be confused with the glob syntax of alternatives `{A,B,C}` which is also supported.

While there have been discussion on man page updates I don't see them yet live in production; the proposed changes should have been related to the Globbing section.